# Specify a Valid number SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Please I need help in fixing the error message I have been getting when I try to INSERT a content to the table below. An example will help me understand it better.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
        EMP_ID      INTEGER     NOT NULL
    , FNAME     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    , LNAME     VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL
    , ADDRESS   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    , SALARY    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    , DOB       DATE            NOT NULL
    , SHIFTS    VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL
    , SSN       CHAR(11)        NOT NULL
    , PHONE         CHAR(12)    NOT NULL
    , HIRING_DATE   CHAR(12)    NOT NULL
    , EMAIL     VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
);
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES(1,'Erica', 'Brandon', '425 Main Street', 'Credit Card', 
       '1965-06-30', 'Evening', '610-24-1111',
       '603-547-8296', '2010-01-16', 'ejohnson@fakemail.com');
```

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm):

```
INSERT INTO EMP 
VALUES(1,
       'Erica',
       'Brandon',
       '425 Main Street',
       'Credit Card',
       TO_DATE('1965-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
       'Evening',
       '610-24-1111',
       '603-547-8296',
       TO_DATE('2010-01-16', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
       'ejohnson@fakemail.com');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c38e/1/0)**</kbd>

It is a good practice to enlist column names like:

```
INSERT INTO EMP(EMP_ID,FNAME,LNAME...)
VALUES (...);
```

You should store `HIRING_DATE` as `DATE` not string.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message, even though I copied and pasted your example given.

Comment: OK I WILL TRY THAT AND SEE

Answer (score 1):

The date format in Oracle depends on the internationalization settings (and the default is not good).   You can use the `date` keyword to specify dates using ISO standard formats:

```
INSERT INTO EMP
    VALUES(1, 'Erica', 'Brandon', '425 Main Street', 'Credit Card', 
           DATE '1965-06-30', 'Evening', '610-24-1111',
           '603-547-8296', '2010-01-16', 'ejohnson@fakemail.com');
```

Notes:

- `HiringDate` should be a date type, not a character type.
- You should list the columns in `EMP` in the `insert`.